# Combine and Comma Separate Rows

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    c.br,
    c.no_,
    CONCAT(c.name, ' ', c.surname) AS Name,
    t.type,
    t.code,
    t.sub,
    GETDATE() AS date,
    c2.name 
FROM
    c 
    INNER JOIN t on c.rowno = t.rowno
    LEFT JOIN termjnt on t.rowno = termjnt.rowno
    LEFT JOIN c c2 on termjnt.rowno_c2 = c2.rowno
WHERE 
    t.status = 'active'
```

here is an output example

[image]

how do I combine the c2.name rows for each no_?
for example, instead of Heather and Humphry being different rows I would like the cell to be "Humphry, Heather"

Comment: you have nothing that will determine which order to sequence your names. or is this not a problem if for example you returned Heather, Humphrey or vice versa?

Comment: order of the names doesn't matter - they do have an ID number that I could pull but it doesn't matter in this instance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join here, but the issue is determining which order to present the names. For this I have simply used alphabetical name order to determine a sequence:

```
WITH TEST
AS
(
SELECT 
    NAME = C.NAME+' '+C.SURNAME,
    NO_,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO_ ORDER BY C.NAME+' '+C.SURNAME DESC) SEQ
FROM C
)
SELECT TEST.NO_, NAMECONCAT = TEST.NAME+', '+TEST2.NAME 
FROM TEST
    LEFT JOIN TEST TEST2
    ON TEST.NO_ = TEST2.NO_
    AND TEST.SEQ = TEST2.SEQ-1
```